# Using cam350 to find errors of a PCB file

Tags: pcb, altium

I want to find errors of a PCB file (like disconnection between tracks and pads, etc) which I have created in Altium designer software. I use Cam350 software for this purpose.
When I run Cam350 I face with some errors like that:

[image: Errors]

I don't understand the meaning of this errors. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To check for disconnections between tracks and pads, and other ways the PCB layout doesn't match the schematic, you should use the PCB Design Rules Check (DRC) in Altium PCB.

Comment: those are groups of errors, not the individual errors